# How to find if android app is started by AndroidOS or ChromeOS's android container?

Tags: android, apk, google-chrome-os, multi-window, androidappsonchromeos

`ChromeOS` has started supporting `Android` apps. https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/optimizing

`Android` apps when running within `ChromeOS` requires a bunch of optimizations and these optimizations apply only to the app when running in chrome environment.

- Is it possible to use the same app APK file for both Android and chrome or should have separate APK files?
- Is it possible to differentiate the environment (Android or ChromeOS) programmatically within the app?

  - Differentiating based on the availability of touchscreen feature is not valid anymore since some Chromebooks ships with touchscreens and can be used as a tablet.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is it possible to use the same app APK file for both Android and chrome or should have separate APK files?**

Yes, it is possible to use same `apk` for `Android` and `ChromeOS` if you don't have any special feature which is not available on `ChromeOS`. No need to create separate APK.

[Device Support](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/device-support):

> You can use the Google Play Store to install Android apps on several
>   Google Chromebooks. This document describes the Chromebooks,
>   Chromeboxes, and Chromebases that can install Android apps, both
>   currently and in upcoming releases of Chrome OS.

If your app will have any feature which is not available on `ChromeOS` then that app will not be available on PlayStore for `ChromeOS` i.e. from `ChromeOS` you will not be able to see that app on PlayStore.

[App manifest compatibility for Chromebooks](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/manifest):

> As you prepare your Android app to run on Chromebooks, you should
>   consider the device features that your app uses. Chromebooks don't
>   support all of the hardware and software features that are available
>   on other devices running Android. If your app requires specific
>   features that aren't supported on Chromebooks, it won't be available
>   for installation on Chromebooks.

**Is it possible to differentiate the environment (Android or ChromeOS) programmatically within the app?**

Yes it is possible to check if app is running on ChromeOS using below code:

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("org.chromium.arc.device_management");
```

Comment: "context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("org.chromium.arc.device_management");" is the official way to check? Or an hack which might not work reliably down the lane?

Comment: @AKh as of now this is official way to check.

Comment: Is @VicJordan this  ("org.chromium.arc.device_management") the only package we need to check to make sure we are running on ChromeOS or is there any additional packages that requires a check?

Comment: @AKh this is the only package enough to check. No need of any additional check